# Booting From a Live USB does not provide "Try Ubuntu Option"

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, live-usb

I have an HP EliteBook that is about 4 years old. It was running windows 10 up until about 8 months ago when I switched over to Ubuntu. Fast Forward to today, I have reinstalled Windows as the only OS for this system. Long-Story short I need to Dual-Boot this machine.

I created a Live USB stick using Rufus with an image of Ubuntu 18.04. I partitioned my harddrive to leave some space for the install. Upon booting into the USB, I am prompted with three options on the GRUB (I think GRUB the purple start up screen):

```
Ubuntu
Advanced Options
System Setup
```

Normally I would see the `Install Ubuntu` or `Try Ubuntu without Installing` options. Upon further inspection, diving into `advanced options` I am shown 3 different kernel versions that I could "load". To my knowledge I reformatted the hard drive so there shouldn't be anything left from the old Ubuntu install.

Another slight issue is that in my BIOS menu when I go to the `Boot Menu` to select the OS to boot into I don't actually see anything on my screen. Neither Windows, or the USB shows up. I just hit enter and Ubuntu is the process that boots up. So it very well could be a boot option to the Old Ubuntu system.

After selecting `Ubuntu` on the menu, I am greeted with the familiar loading screen. However this lasts for about 5 minutes before booting into "BusyBox" which I've never even heard of before. I found some answers online regarding corrupted partitions or something similar where a few "BusyBox" commands would fix the issue, but this did not work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem here is twofold: 1. You don't understand UEFI (which is what you have, not BIOS) and then you don't understand that 2. The USB isn't actually booting, what's booting instead is the remaining EFI file from your previous Ubuntu installation that obviously can't boot because the Ubuntu system partition is no longer there.